# Why can't I get a resource file in my android project?

Tags: android

I have the following three lines of code in my project:

```
String filePathString = "android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/res/raw/oldphone_mono.wav";
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists()) {/* do something */}
```

At runtime, the filePathString has the value `android.resource://com.johntestapp/res/raw/oldphone_mono.wav` .  In my project, I can see that I have the file oldphone_mono.wav in my /res/raw/ directory.  But for some reason, f.exists() still evaluates to false.  What's wrong with the way i'm declaring the path to my wav file?

Comment: Try `myActivity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.oldphone_mono)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.oldphone_mono);` instead.

Comment: but then I would like to eventually do a `MediaPlayer p = new MediaPlayer();  p.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(filePathString));`  .  Is ther ea way to convert inputStream to filePathString?

Comment: In that case what you want is `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oldphone_mono);`